# Progress bar on mlr::impute()

Tags: r, mlr

I would like to process bigger datasets in a generic fashion using MLR, specifically using the impute and the reimpute functions.
Since the data it has to fill and the size of the dataset, I would like to know some details to how long it is assumed to take.

Does anyone know a way to come to such a solution?

So basically I would like ’mlr:impute()’ to have a ‘Verbose = TRUE’ functionallity, which does not exist.

regards,

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not supported at the moment and there are no plans to add it. The reason is that it is very difficult to predict how long such an operation will take -- in fact, this is a machine learning problem in itself. Most of the techniques mlr uses for imputation and other purposes are provided by third-party libraries, so can't easily extract progress information.

Even if we could predict the time an operation will take with reasonable accuracy, the overhead of doing so would make short operations much slower, as well as requiring more memory. And even in this case, the results would be different from machine to machine (will it run out of memory?), complicating a reliable deployment further.